# Shrink Sticky Header Logo on Mobile Scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, header

I've been trying to figure out a way to have the sticky header that we only have applied on our mobile version of our Shopify site, shrink the header logo when you scroll down. And then have the header logo resize to it's original size when scrolling back to the very top. Of course if this shrinks the entire header size on mobile scroll that works!

This was used originally but the logo would not properly resize to it's original size when scrolling all the way back up. Instead it would strangely get smaller when going on different pages on the mobile site:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){ 
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 10){      
$('.site-header__logo-image img').addClass("manage_width");
  } 
else{
//back to default styles
$('.site-header__logo-image img').removeClass("manage_width");
 }
});
```

I've tried variations of JS, CSS, and HTML but nothing has seemed to work so far. If anyone has code that we could apply to the site for mobile only I would really appreciate it!  Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your exact set up but it sounds like you will need to add a event listener in javascript to detect when a user is scrolling.
To change the size of the logo you could add a new class to it when scrolling.

You will also have to detect when the user has scrolled to the top, in order to change the logo back to it's original size.
The code should look something like this:

CSS

```
.logo {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

.logo--small {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

JS

```
// get logo
var logo = document.getElementById('logo');

// listen for scroll
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  // add small size class
  logo.classList.add('logo--small');
  // if user is at top of screen and has the small class, then remove it
  if (window.scrollTop == 0 && logo.classList.contains('logo--small')) {
        logo.classList.remove('logo--small');
    }        
});
```

You could of course apply a css transition to the class to make it a better experience, and also detect whether or not a user is scrolling up or down, and shrink / grow the logo accordingly, as opposed to simple resizing when the user gets to the very top.

Comment: Hey Johnny, appreciate such a speedy response!! I went ahead and tried to implement both the CSS and JS but it didn't seem to work at all on the mobile version (looks like it might be breaking the menu functionality just a little). Any tips?

Comment: Sounds like something is interfering maybe. have you run anyway console logs to make sure this piece of code is running at all?

Comment: It shouldn't be affecting the functionality unless you have something else running that could interfere, all we are doing here is adding/removing classes... Hard to tell without knowing exactly your situation

Comment: Oh okay gotcha. I copied our JS here just for reference, I'm not entirely sure what on here could be interfering with this code directly: https://codepen.io/nikki-s/pen/NWrBrry

Comment: Hi Nikki, wow that is a lot of code... I couldn't possibly know without using your code, but are there any other scroll event listeners in there? There are a lot of references to scrolling when I search, i would think there probably are other functions handling scrolling that might be causing a conflict.